# I am trying to program a 2d shooter game in pygame and it shows an index error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Tags: python, index-error

```
animation_types = ['idle', 'run', 'jump']
  for animation in animation_types:
    temp_list = []
  num_of_frames = len(os.listdir(f'img/{self.char_type}/{animation}'))
  for i in range(num_of_frames):
     img = pygame.image.load(f'img/{self.char_type}/{animation}/{i}.png')
     img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))
     temp_list.append(img)
     temp_list = []
  self.animation_list.append(temp_list)
   
  self.image = self.animation_list[self.action][self.frame_index]
  self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
  self.rect.center = (x, y)
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

when I run this part of the code it shows the index error "out of range" and I have tried everything but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You are always clearing the list after you add an image to it:

```
temp_list.append(img)
temp_list = []
```

Then you add the empty list to you animation list

```
self.animation_list.append(temp_list)
```

There are other problems in your code too. I'm assuming you expect this line to create multiple `temp_list` but that's not the case, this creates and overwrites the same one on every iteration of the loop.

```
for animation in animation_types:
    temp_list = []
```

I suggest that you use a debugger to check for these kinds of errors. A lot of editors include debuggers that will allow you to inspect the code (VSCode and Pycharm for example), pause it's execution at some point and inspect the content of the variables.